# Not enough permission error when upload CSV file with audiences via Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to upload CSV file with custom audience for audience match. I'm using Linkedin Media Upload API with `media_type` equal to `ad_segments` just like in api guide https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/ads/account-targeting. My POST request

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/media/upload?media_type=ad_segments HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/*+json
Authorization: Bearer {my_token}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=U_FM4CX-g_nOF0dM0UGj4G5V_N4DKGA
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_144
Host: api.linkedin.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21980

--U_FM4CX-g_nOF0dM0UGj4G5V_N4DKGA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="audience.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

email
7e27ef2718f1aaddb03936077714a60244e380ef09e27504fcb3184a2af7b6ea
cb39d1f4b7f209e5bb36f72c20aa4c0d0b2ecf7b21d99d5d6cfc4b4c81898b24
.
.
--U_FM4CX-g_nOF0dM0UGj4G5V_N4DKGA--
```

I get

```
{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access media resource","status":403}
```

I double-checked that the user grants `rw_ad_campaigns` permission to the application but still I get "not enough permissions" error. 
Uploading images via Media Upload API works fine. It's just CSV file for audiences match that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the "media" controller/endpoint, you need to be a LinkedIn "Partner":

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs